# JSON String with multiple fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am currently sending some simple json from an iOS app to server using the following:

```
NSData *jsonData = [@"{ \"item\": \"hat\" }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I would like to add a bunch of other fields and values.

What would be the appropriate syntax to include more fields?

Something like

```
 NSData *jsonData = [@"{ \"item\": \"hat\",\"id\":2,\"color\":\"blue\" }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or is there a better way to do this such by sending a dictionary?

Comment: Why not create an `NSDictionary` with the values you want. Then convert the dictionary to a JSON string to send to the server?

Comment: As @rmaddy said, create an NSDictionary and serialise it using NSJSONSerialization class (You'll get NSData)

Comment: JSON should really only be considered as a serialization method, not a data structure.  Build an appropriate data structure, then serialize it for delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create an `NSDictionary` containing the required fields and the serialize it to JSON :

```
NSDictionary *package = @{@"item":@"hat",@"id":2,@"color":@"blue"};
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:package 
                                    options:0 error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating the Dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setObject:'Value' forKey:'Key']; //adding values
```

You can use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

convert NSDictionary to Json string like so:

```
NSString *jsonString = [dictionary JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil];
```

or you can use [SBJson](http://www.superloopy.io/json-framework/api/3.0/)

```
NSString *jsonString = [dictionary JSONRepresentation];
```

and you can do it without third party framework:

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryOrArrayToOutput 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```